# How to add +1 to the last two digits of a number?

Tags: excel

I want a way to do the following

```
Original Data         I want result as
507-413-0109        507-413-0110
507-430-5409        507-430-5410
507-450-6649        507-450-6650
507-450-8640        507-450-8651
507-451-1563        507-451-1574
```

if the original number is 2133-2322 , I want it as 2133-2333 .
The last two digits should increase by value 1.
But , if there is a 9, 
9+1 = 0
and
0+1 = 1

how to do it in Excel ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the case when the original ends in 99?

Comment: ....or when the original ends in 9999....? Aren't those last two wrong? I'd expect 41 and 64?

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the 3rd column of numer (0109, 5409, ...) in a particular column. You can use the function RIGHT(A1,1) (where A1 is the cell which contains the 207-413-0109 string).
Then you just add +1 to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
=REPLACE($A1,11,2,TEXT(IF(VALUE(RIGHT($A1)) = 9, MOD(VALUE(RIGHT($A1,2))+1,100), VALUE(RIGHT($A1,2))+11),"00"))
```

Put this in cell C1, then copy to C2 through C5.

I assumed that if the number ends in 99, then it replaces 99 with 00.

This will handle the 99 case as a 4-digit number instead of two, all other things being same:

```
=REPLACE($A1,9,4,TEXT(IF(VALUE(RIGHT($A1)) = 9, MOD(VALUE(RIGHT($A1,4))+1,10000), VALUE(RIGHT($A1,4))+11),"0000"))
```

So 1599 will become 1600 instead of 1500. And 9999 will just become 0000.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data begins in the "A1" spreadsheet position, if you put the folling formula in the "B1" cell, and then copy it downward, it should derive the values you're for which you're looking

`=LEFT(A2,10) & RIGHT(TEXT(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,2)) + 1,"00"),2)`

Comment: That doesn't give the correct result when the original doesn't end in 9.

Comment: Nice. I like it. :) I'm still waiting to hear from @Shijil what he wants to do with the 99 case. :)